# Almost Done... Post Format Code

Tags: php, excerpt, post-formats

I would REALLY appreciate some help with this, I have been working on it for a while and am so close to done I can taste it.

I need each post format excerpt to have the same excerpt code as the default excerpt (used without post formats) which is provided as "Code 1". This MUST contain the excerpt_wrap and exerpt_inside along with the conditional div class. Basically, everything in this code... simply figure out how to integrate it into the second code everywhere it says "CODE GOES HERE"...

Code 1:

```
<!-- Begin excerpt wrap -->
        <div class="excerpt_wrap">
          <div class="excerpt_inside">

<!-- No post format -->

            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>

            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thmb-index' ); ?>
            </a>

            <?php } ?>

            <div class="excerpt_content<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) echo ' with-thumbnail'; ?>"> <span class="index_title">

    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

              <?php the_title(); ?>

              </a>

</span> <span class="sub-title">By

              <?php the_author_posts_link( ); ?>

              <span class="sub-title-divider">|</span>

              <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?>

              <span class="sub-title-divider">|</span> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>/#commentlist">

              <?php comments_number( 'No comments', 'One comment', '% comments' ); ?>

              </a></span>

              <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

            </div>

            <!-- End excerpt wrap -->          

          </div>
        </div>
```

Code 2:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>



<div id="container">

<div id="post_content2">

<div id="main_index">

<div class="main_adjust"> 



<!-- Grab posts -->

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>







            <!-- Post formats -->

<?php

if ( has_post_format( 'aside' )) {

CODE GOES HERE

}

elseif ( has_post_format( 'chat' )) {

CODE GOES HERE

}

elseif ( has_post_format( 'gallery' )) {

CODE GOES HERE

}

elseif ( has_post_format( 'image' )) {

CODE GOES HERE

}

elseif ( has_post_format( 'link' )) {

CODE GOES HERE

}

elseif ( has_post_format( 'quote' )) {

CODE GOES HERE

}

elseif ( has_post_format( 'status' )) {

CODE GOES HERE

}

elseif ( has_post_format( 'video' )) {

CODE GOES HERE

}

elseif ( has_post_format( 'audio' )) {

CODE GOES HERE

}

else {

$format = get_post_format();

if ( false === $format ) {

 ?>



<!-- Begin excerpt wrap -->

        <div class="excerpt_wrap">

          <div class="excerpt_inside">





<!-- No post format -->

            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>

            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">

            <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thmb-index' ); ?>

            </a>

            <?php } ?>

            <div class="excerpt_content<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) echo ' with-thumbnail'; ?>"> <span class="index_title">

    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

              <?php the_title(); ?>

              </a>

</span> <span class="sub-title">By

              <?php the_author_posts_link( ); ?>

              <span class="sub-title-divider">|</span>

              <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?>

              <span class="sub-title-divider">|</span> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>/#commentlist">

              <?php comments_number( 'No comments', 'One comment', '% comments' ); ?>

              </a></span>

              <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

            </div>





            <!-- End excerpt wrap -->          

          </div>

        </div>



<?php } // ending the if ( false === $format ) ... 



    } // end else



        ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>







        <!-- Next/Previous entries -->

       <div class="mp_archive">

          <div id="more_posts">

            <div class="oe">

              <?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older') ?>

            </div>

            <div class="re">

              <?php previous_posts_link ('Newer &raquo;') ?>

            </div>

          </div>

          </div>





</div>

</div>

</div>



  <?php get_sidebar(); ?>



</div>

</div>



<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize the Wordpress function get_template_part();

Create several template files in your theme directory called content-POST_FORMAT_TYPE.php - Example: content-gallery.php and content-chat.php

```
if(has_post_format('gallery'))
    get_template_part('content', 'gallery');
elseif(has_post_format('chat')
    get_template_part('content', 'chat');
else
    the_content();
```

This approach makes your code blocks reusable in multiple templates. Hope this helps you out.